# how to change default module in Zend 2

Tags: zend-framework, module, routes, zend-framework2, default

I am new to ZendFeamerwork version 2. I could easily change the default controller in Zend1 but it seems very difficult to me to find out how to change default module in Zend2.

I searched over google but there is no easy solution.

I just created a module named "CsnUser" I can access this module via the following url

```
http://localhost/zcrud/public/csn-user/
```

I want csn-user to load instead of "application" module i.e url should be

```
http://localhost/zcrud/public/
```

or

```
http://localhost/zcrud/
```

Please let me know how to get this done.

Comment: So we've either got a routing problem or an issue in your application config. Could you provide your `application.config.php` and your `module.config.php` for your `CsnUser` module?

Comment: @Svengali there is no issue in accessing csn-user. My question is to make csn-user to default module.

Comment: There is no such thing in zf2. When you have your application routes '/'  you can make this route of your home pointing to your csn default controller. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Hoolis comment:

You have to set that action on this route

```
'home' => array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'That\Namespace\CsnUser',
                'action'     => 'index'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

In the skeleton application this route is set in the Application Module, but you can move this somewhere or edit it.